# Counting total rows and rows under condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, count, pivot, aggregate-functions

I have `table1` looking like:

```
docid   val1   val2   val3   value
----------------------------------
001     1      1      null   10
001     null   null   null    5
001     1      null   1      20
001     1      null   null    7
001     null   null   null   15
002     null   null   1      30
002     null   null   null    2
```

I need as output:

- Per `docid`
- the total number of rows that exist for that `docid`
- and the sum of `value` for those rows
- the number of rows that hit on the condition: `val1 = 1 or val2 = 1 or val3 = 1`
- and the sum of `value` for those rows

As follows:

```
docid   total_rows   total_rows_value   rows_with_val   val_rows_value
001     5            57                 3               37
002     2            1                  32              2
```

What I have until now:

```
select   [docid],
         count(1) as [rows_with_val],
         sum([value]) as [val_rows_value]
from     table1
where    val1 = 1 or val2 = 1 or val3 = 1
group by [docid]
;
```

This will only give the hits though. How can I account for both? I understand by deleting the where-clause, but where do I put it then? I have been reading about case statement (in my select) but don't know how to apply it here.

Answer (score 1):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
select docid, count(*) total_rows, sum(value) as sum_value,
    sum(case when 1 in (val1, val2, val3) then 1 else 0 end) as cnt_val1,
    sum(case when 1 in (val1, val2, val3) then value else 0 end) as sum_val1
from mytable
group by docid
```